# Unable to install vitess using vitess operator on red hat openshift server

Tags: mysql, installation, vitess

I tried to install vitess on vanilla kubernetes and I am able to install it successfully.
I tried the same using open shift red hat server but i have encountered the below error. What are the specific configurations required to install the same?
I have used the vitess guide and initial_cluster.yaml to install the cluster.

https://vitess.io/docs/17.0/get-started/operator/

`````
time="2023-07-10T06:13:31Z" level=info msg="Reconciling VitessCluster" VitessCluster=example controller=VitessCluster namespace=test
{"level":"error","ts":"2023-07-10T06:13:34Z","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"vitessshard-controller","object":{"name":"example-commerce-x-x-0f5afee6","namespace":"test"},"namespace":"test","name":"example-commerce-x-x-0f5afee6","reconcileID":"ed9a301a-11c9-410b-8cfe-c19701e1ad41","error":"pods \"example-vttablet-zone1-2548885007-46a852d0\" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context 
constraint: [provider \"anyuid\": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider restricted: .spec.securityContext.fsGroup: Invalid value: []int64{999}: 999 is not an allowed group, spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 999: must be in the ranges: [1000700000, 1000709999], spec.initContainers[1].securityContext.runAsUser: 
Invalid value: 999: must be in the ranges: [1000700000, 1000709999], spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 999: must be in the ranges: [1000700000, 1000709999], spec.containers[1].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 999: must be in the ranges: [1000700000, 1000709999], spec.containers[2].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 999: must be in the ranges: [1000700000, 1000709999], provider \"nonroot\": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider \"hostmount-anyuid\":
 Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider \"machine-api-termination-handler\": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider \"hostnetwork\": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider \"hostaccess\": 
Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider \"node-exporter\": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider \"privileged\": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount]",
"stacktrace":"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:329\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:274\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:235"}````
`````